# Getting deployment error in jboss

Tags: spring, jsf, jboss

I am trying to build my project and run in JBoss. I'm able to build successfully but when I'm starting my JBoss server it's showing the below error. I'm not even able to understand whats the reason behind this.

here is the entire stack trace:

```
13:00:13,625 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (version 11.1)
13:00:13,781 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-2) The listener "com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
13:00:13,781 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/provider-pay]] (MSC service thread 1-2) No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
13:00:13,813 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/provider-pay]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Set web app root system property: 'webapp.root' = [D:\tools\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\tmp\vfs\temp852b611c04659912\provider-pay.war-f6e1379c73e54ccb\]
13:00:17,016 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-2) Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final
13:00:17,422 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) 02 Jun 2014 13:00:17  INFO DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@696c65: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationPro
cessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationP
rocessor,userServiceImpl,wholesalerServiceImpl,userDAO,wholesalerDAO,binController,wholesalerListController,loginController,org.springframework.context.config.internalBeanConfigurerAspect,org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0,DataSource,SessionFactory,or
g.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,txManager,org.springframework
.security.filterChains,org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy,org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.PortResolverImpl#0,org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.security.authentication
.ProviderManager#0,org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy#0,org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0,org.springframework.security.web
.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler#0,org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0,org.springframework.secu
rity.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0,org.springframework.security.userDetailsServiceFactory,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0,org.springframework.security.provisioning.
InMemoryUserDetailsManager#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0,org.springframework.security.authenticationManager,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostP
rocessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
13:00:17,453 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) 02 Jun 2014 13:00:17 ERROR ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
13:00:17,453 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'binController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire fie
ld: com.prime.tfb.service.binmanagement.BinmanagementService com.prime.tfb.web.controller.BinController.binmanagementservice; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.prime.tfb.service.binmanagement.BinmanagementService] fou
nd for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
13:00:17,453 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
13:00:17,453 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
13:00:17,453 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
13:00:17,453 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
13:00:17,453 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
13:00:17,453 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
13:00:17,469 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
13:00:17,469 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
13:00:17,469 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
13:00:17,469 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
13:00:17,469 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
13:00:17,469 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
13:00:17,469 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
13:00:17,469 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
13:00:17,469 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392)
13:00:17,469 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850)
13:00:17,469 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90)
13:00:17,469 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
13:00:17,469 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
13:00:17,469 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
13:00:17,484 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
13:00:17,484 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
13:00:17,484 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.prime.tfb.service.binmanagement.BinmanagementService com.prime.tfb.web.controller.BinController.binmanagementservice; nested exception is org.springf
ramework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.prime.tfb.service.binmanagement.BinmanagementService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.fa
ctory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
13:00:17,484 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517)
13:00:17,484 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
13:00:17,484 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
13:00:17,484 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)    ... 21 more
13:00:17,484 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.prime.tfb.service.binmanagement.BinmanagementService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate
for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
13:00:17,484 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:988)
13:00:17,484 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
13:00:17,500 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
13:00:17,500 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
13:00:17,500 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)    ... 23 more
13:00:17,500 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/provider-pay]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreat
ionException: Error creating bean with name 'binController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.prime.tfb.service.binmanagement.BinmanagementService com.prime.tfb.web.controller.BinCon
troller.binmanagementservice; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.prime.tfb.service.binmanagement.BinmanagementService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this depen
dency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289) [spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146) [spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) [spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) [spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296) [spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) [spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628) [spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) [spring-context-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) [spring-context-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.prime.tfb.service.binmanagement.BinmanagementService com.prime.tfb.web.controller.BinController.binmanagementservice; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
 No qualifying bean of type [com.prime.tfb.service.binmanagement.BinmanagementService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517) [spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) [spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286) [spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        ... 21 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.prime.tfb.service.binmanagement.BinmanagementService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.sp
ringframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:988) [spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858) [spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770) [spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489) [spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        ... 23 more

13:00:17,625 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-2) Initializing Mojarra 2.1.7-jbossorg-1 (20120227-1401) for context '/provider-pay'
13:00:19,719 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.managedbean] (MSC service thread 1-2) JSF1074: Managed bean named 'loginController' has already been registered.  Replacing existing managed bean class type com.prime.tfb.web.controller.LoginController with com.prime.tfb.web.controller
.LoginController.
13:00:21,422 INFO  [org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener] (MSC service thread 1-2) Running on PrimeFaces 4.0
13:00:21,453 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-2) Error listenerStart
13:00:21,453 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-2) Context [/provider-pay] startup failed due to previous errors
13:00:21,469 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/provider-pay]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
13:00:21,469 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/provider-pay]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Shutting down log4j
13:00:21,484 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./provider-pay: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./provider-pay: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:95)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]

13:00:21,484 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
13:00:21,484 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 27781ms - Started 435 of 514 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 76 services are passive or on-demand)
13:00:21,703 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "provider-pay.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./provider-pay" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service j
boss.web.deployment.default-host./provider-pay: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}
13:00:21,703 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./provider-pay: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./provider-pay: JBAS018040: Failed to start context

13:00:21,719 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./provider-pay" => "org.jboss.m
sc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./provider-pay: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}}}
13:00:23,531 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment provider-pay.war in 1825ms
```

here is my com.prime.tfb.service.binmanagement.BinmanagementService.java:

```
public interface BinmanagementService {

@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public void addBinmanagement(BinManagement binmanagement);

@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public void deleteBinmanagement(BinManagement binmanagement);

@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public void updateBinmanagement(BinManagement binmanagement);

public BinManagement getBinmanagementById(int id);


public List<BinManagement> getBinmanagement(); 
 }
```

and com.prime.tfb.web.controller.BinController.java :

```
@ManagedBean
@Controller
@RequestScoped
public class BinController {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final String SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String ERROR = "error";


private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BinController.class);



 List<BinManagement> BinManagementlist ;


 @Autowired
 BinmanagementService binmanagementservice;



public BinController()
{

}

public BinmanagementService getbinBinmanagementService(){
    return binmanagementservice;
}

public void setBinmanagementService(BinmanagementService binmanagementservice){

    this.binmanagementservice = binmanagementservice;
}



/**
 *
 * Redirects the login request directly to spring security check.
 * Leave this method as it is to properly support spring security.
 * 
 * @return
 * @throws ServletException
 * @throws IOException
 */

 public List<BinManagement> getBinmanagementList(User user) throws IOException {  

    List<BinManagement> list =  binmanagementservice.getBinmanagement();

    System.out.println("Giving emtpy List..." + list);
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Welcome", user.getUserId());


    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();  
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    ExternalContext ec=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    ec.redirect("admin/bin_management.xhtml");      

    return list;

}

}
```

and web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/
XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/
ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/
web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/
xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>Provider Pay</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>

 <context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/providerpay_spring_config.xml
        /WEB-INF/security.xml
    </param-value>

</context-param>
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


    <!-- Enable Spring Security -->
<filter>
 <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
 <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<!-- Allow login pages with JSF which redirects to security check,
 therefore we have to add the forward entry here -->
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
 </filter-mapping>
  </web-app>
```

and my BinmanagementServiceImpl.java :

```
public class BinmanagementServiceImpl implements BinmanagementService {

@Autowired
public BinManagementDAO binmanagementDAO;

@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public void addBinmanagement(BinManagement binmanagement) {
    getBinmanagementDAO().addBinmanagement(binmanagement);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public void deleteBinmanagement(BinManagement binmanagement) {
    getBinmanagementDAO().deleteBinmanagement(binmanagement);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public void updateBinmanagement(BinManagement binmanagement) {
    getBinmanagementDAO().updateBinmanagement(binmanagement);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


public BinManagement getBinmanagementById(int id) {

    return getBinmanagementDAO().getBinManagementByID(id);
}


public List<BinManagement> getBinmanagement() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<BinManagement> bm = new ArrayList<BinManagement>();
    bm.add(new BinManagement());
    bm.add(new BinManagement());
    return bm;
}


public BinManagementDAO getBinmanagementDAO() {
    return binmanagementDAO;
}

public void setBinmanagementDAO(BinManagementDAO binmanagementDAO) {
    this.binmanagementDAO = binmanagementDAO;

}

 }
```

can any one please help me on this issue?

Comment: Is this the entire stack strace? Please provide the server logs right from `starting deployment of provider-pay.war`.

Comment: as per the text limit i couldn't added entire stack trace but yes i have added almost stack trace which could help you to trace out the problem

Comment: We need to look at your Spring configuration. One relevant exception is `Could not autowire field: com.prime.tfb.service.binmanagement.BinmanagementService com.prime.tfb.web.controller.BinController.binmanagementservice`. If you can provide source code of BinController, BinmanagementService and xml configuration of Java configuration for your web app, it would help.

Comment: i have added just now, those may help you in tracing out the problem

Comment: Where do you define an instance of `BinmanagementServiceImpl`? I don't see any annotations on `BinmanagementServiceImpl` class nor you have posted any xml configuration that should define a `BinmanagementServiceImpl` `<bean />`.

Comment: i have created an instance of BinmanagementService in my controller and made it autowired with autowired annotation

Comment: That's not an instance creation. Is just a reference to an instance of `BinmanagementService`. The reference injected with `@Autowired`. The instance must be created somewhere else. Where?

Comment: Post the content of `providerpay_spring_config.xml` file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54930/discussion-between-preeth-and-andrei-stefan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring, to be able to autowire dependencies, needs to know about those instances. It seems your `BinmanagementServiceImpl` is not known by Spring. Add a `@Component` annotation to your `BinmanagementServiceImpl` class.